# How to initialize a Localstorage?

Tags: reactjs

In the code below I am trying to set branches of a store with Select, My aim is to store the value of selected branch in local storage and show the same branch on reload, On first load it throws error since I am not initializing the values of local storage. How to resolve this??

```
const [selectedBranch, setSelectedBranch] = useState(LocalStorage.getItem("branch") ?? brand);
    
        function handleChangeBranch(value: any) {
    
        AdvertiseService.fetchNewStore(
          `${value}`,
          (store: any) => {
            // brand = store;
            LocalStorage.setItem("branch", store)
            setSelectedBranch(store);
    
          },
          () => { },
          () => { }
        );
        setBranchChanged(true)
    
      }
    
    </div>
                <Button
                  className="brand__store-details--actions-btn store-change"
                >
                  <Select
                    suffixIcon={<CaretDownOutlined />}
                    defaultValue={LocalStorage.getItem("branch").id}
                    style={{ border: "none" }}
                    onChange={handleChangeBranch}
                  >
                    {branches &&
                      branches.branches?.map((branch: any) => (
                        <Option
                          value={branch.id}
                          className="advertise-branch-list-item"
                          key={branch.id}
                        >
                          {branch.name}
                        </Option>
                      ))}
                  </Select>
                </Button>
              </div>
```

Comment: you have to make/initialise the localstoarge id `branch` before calling/getting it in `useState`

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that or give the code line for that???

Comment: what is a brand value? On which line did you get error?

Comment: defaultValue={LocalStorage.getItem("branch") ? LocalStorage.getItem("branch").id : "" }

Comment: try to  set  the `defaultValue` as the useState value instead i.e. `defaultValue = {selectedBranch.id || 1}`

Comment: make an initial state for `setState` , `const [selectedBranch, setSelectedBranch] = useState(LocalStorage.getItem("branch") || { id: '1' .. //the default object });`

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot!!

Comment: can i add an answer and you may accept it ?

Comment: @ShoyebMemon is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `defaultValue` as the `useState` value instead i.e.

`defaultValue = {selectedBranch.id || 1}`

also ,make an initial state for `setState`.

**eg :-**

```
const [selectedBranch, setSelectedBranch] = 
useState(LocalStorage.getItem("branch") || 
 { id: '1' .. //the default object });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `.id` on the localStorage value.

Local storage treats values as string, When you want to store an object in `localStorage` you should always stringify it `localStorage.setItem('key': JSON.stringify(obj))` before save and parse it like `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'))`.

you can also get localStorage value by simply doing `localStorage.keyName`

```
const [selectedBranch, setSelectedBranch] = useState(localStorage.branch ? JSON.parse(localStorage.branch) : brand);
```